# How to create smaller mini camera view like in Tumblr iPhone app image picker

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-camera

I would like to know how Tumblr app is adding a mini camera live view on collection view cell in their app? Is it UIImagePickerController of type camera resized? I would be glad if someone could give more idea on this implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do that, you're going to have to use `AVFoundation`.  You can size and position the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` however you'd like.

Comment: Found this as a great sample code for the task. https://github.com/ijason/FaceCamTest